# How can we read keys stored from cpp file (NDK Implementation) in manifest and build gradle files

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-manifest

As mentioned, i have an ndk implementation to store and api keys,
We can read these keys in activity etc, but is there a way to read these in manifest and build.gradle files?
Since keys like google geo api keys are to referenced in manifest.

Thank you